# PDOException: could not find driver after server reboot

Tags: php, apache, pdo

When rebooting the server (RHEL6, Apache 2.2, PHP 7.2) I always get the error "PDOException: could not find driver". Apache is started automatically via httpd init script.

After an apachectl stop | start everything works fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: `sudo yum install php72-php-pdo`

Comment: Sounds more like a sysadmin question than a programming question. Try asking over at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: php72-php-pdo is already installed.

Comment: I will ask this question in the Server Fault area as suggested.Thanks.